# How should I understand this interpretation?

Tags: communication, wireless, digital-communications, telecommunications

Studying spatial diversity in telecommunication engineering (*Fundamentals of Wireless Communication*, D. Tse and P. Viswannath), I read this paragraph.

$${\text {In}}\,{\|}{\textbf h}{\|}^{2}{\text {SNR}}=L{\text {SNR}}{\cdot}{{1} \over {L}}{\|}{\textbf h}{\|}^{2},\,$$

> The first term corresponds to the power gain: by having multiple receive antennas  and coherent combining at the receiver, the effective total received signal power increases linearly with L.
> The second term reflects the diversity gain: by averaging over multiple independent signal paths, the probability that the overall gain is small is decreased.

Looking at the formula, I think those types of gain are cancelled out being multiplied, thus we cannot get any type of gain. The book says that we can get both gains. Can you comment what am I missing?